# What are the possible causes of an LC low-pass filter not attenuating in its bandstop?

Tags: power-supply, filter, passive-networks

I've got an [AC-DC power supply](https://www.meanwell.com/webapp/product/search.aspx?prod=DRC-180) which has an amount of ripple which is unsatisfatory for my application, ~250 mVpp, sometimes even 600 mVpp when there is a DC-DC downstream (for some reason).

I'd like to bring that down to 100 mVpp or less using an LC low-pass filter - which should also, I think, decouple the two switching controllers that may cause this increased ripple when a DC-DC is present downstream.

I thought to myself this would be easily fixed with an LC filter downstream of the AC-DC. The switching frequency of the AC-DC is 360 kHz, so I chose [an inductor of 10 μH](https://www.digikey.ca/en/products/detail/abracon-llc/AIRD-01-100K/2660650) capable of handling my load current of 4.5 A without saturating, and slapped a 10 μF ceramic cap (taken from an assortment) rated for 50 V when my bus is 35 V, meaning the cut-off is supposed to be 16 kHz for an attenuation of that ripple by a factor of 60 in theory.

[image]

I know my filter is soldered correctly, because I checked it a gazillion times using continuity checks and the LCR meter (and the inductor on its own), and yet the AC-DC's output passes through nearly unencumbered - barely divided by half.

I know there are parasitics to take into account such as SRF, but I should not get as low as a factor 2, should I? Especially given that I've increased the capacitance by a factor 10 (120 μF) and it doesn't do anything more. It even worsens the noise amplitude slightly.

Am I wrong in thinking a LC filter should do the job here and that something's afoot?

Note that, to my great demise especially in this instant, I do not own a function generator to actually plot the bode chart of the filter.

Comment: What are the load conditions when you measured 600 mV or ripple? What is the source impedance of the regulator? When you calculated the attenuation, how did you model the load? Open circuit or with some current flowing into the load?

Comment: In order to design a filter you need to know the source impedance and the load impedance.

Comment: I know, it's open circuit test conditions for now in the presented case and the source impedance is assumed to be about 0.1R worst-case by calculation but I fail to see how this would explain the presented behaviour in any way.

Comment: In the 600mVpp case there was about 130mA supplied to a 24V buck, why?

Comment: I am just probing. One thing, though, at 360 kHz the output impedance of the regulator will not be 0.1 Ohm. It will be complex. You will be "feeling" the output filter on the DC-DC.

Comment: Maybe the inductor has a lot of parasitic capacitance at 360 kHz? The windings couple to each other capacitively. What is the SRF of the inductor, or do you have a model or chart for it that models the high-frequency behavior?

Comment: Thanks. The datasheet does not say. I was under the assumption that the SRF would be in the MHz range for a 10uH of this size but I'm also here to get others' opinion on that - I might buy another one if needs be.

Comment: Do you feel like your oscilloscope probing technique is beyond reproach? It is not so difficult for 100 mV or more to couple into an oscilloscope one way or another.

Comment: Yeah I agree with you about the inductor. I am just listing the things I can think of.

Comment: I've tested the same technique on a benchtop and the only thing that's common is 125Hz spikes that I know are due to picked up radiated noise. Sure, go ahead it's appreciated!

Comment: Zoom in on the noise (<10us/div). Is it high frequency? Does it show up when probing GND to GND (probe ground clipped to tip and 0V)?  It may be common mode, which needs a different filter type. Show layout and probing technique?

Comment: If the purple trace is the input then it looks like a a case of bad ripple from DCM/burst mode. You may have better results with beads and (some) 10u+100n caps right nest to the ICs/devices, themselves.

Comment: Ceramic capacitors have a strong [capacitance-voltage dependence](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/580393/capacitors-voltage-dependent-capacitance).